# Training Haar Cascade in windows 10

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to create a custom haar cascade file and i am following this example
https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~m.rezaei/Tutorials/Creating_a_Cascade_of_Haar-Like_Classifiers_Step_by_Step.pdf

In step 4, I have to run the following command to create a vector file from the info.txt file for the positive images

```
createsamples.exe -info positive/info.txt -vec vector/facevector.vec -num
200 -w 24 -h 24
```

or run the batch file samples_creation.bat. But when i run the code or execute the batch file I get the following error message.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was in the way my positive images were named. As indicated in this post http://answers.opencv.org/question/186072/bad-argument-in-function-cvreleasedata-how-to-fix-the-error/ I had to rename my positive images.

Comment: afair, spaces are a problem, too.